# Select query too slow > 5min

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table`MyTable` with 29,000 rows.

```
MyTable structure {
  StudentId bigint,
  ....
}
```

Number of columns > 10 columns. The database in the hosting server.

From SSMS i execute the query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
```

Is it normal that the execution lasts more than 5 min?

Comment: How are you executing this? Do you mean in some sort of SQL query browser or in a programming language?

Comment: What is the structure of the table? Are there concurrent transactions performing any `UPDATE`,`DELETE`,`INSERT` on the table? How long does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable` take?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are executing the statement remotely (not on the same box as the database), you could be seeing an issue with the amount of bandwidth between you and the database.

Comment: Do you see the same issue when you do a `SELECT StudentId FROM dbo.MyTable` ?? `SELECT *` can often run into more problems than when you actually specify the columns you want...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, retrieving all the data from a remote database is never a good idea. You are using an important share of bandwidth. Hopefully, the query you are using is only used for debugging purpose and should never hit production.

You did not mention if it took 5 minutes before you started receiving something or if you are receiving your data over the course of that 5 minutes, at a constant rate.

In the first situation, not receiving rows at all might indicating a that a lock is effective on your table, due to another operation.

In the latter situation, you are constantly receiving rows, but at a slow rate. Bandwidth and server load play a big part in that. To get you a rough idea of the amount of data that you are downloading, run this stored procedure:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'YourTableName';
```

Consider that the server has to upload that data and that you have to download the data.

Binary and xml fields (also called BLOB field) usually take a lot of data and you may not be able to control the amount of data stored by the user in those field.

Try checking the size of your variable length fields (varchar, xml and varbinary) by running a DATALENGTH on your column:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(MyField) FROM MyTable
```

You can also get an average:

```
SELECT AVG(DATALENGTH(MyField)) FROM MyTable
```

A good idea concerning BLOB field is to retrieve them only when needer and not when you are loading a list of data.

For example, assume a XML field stored in a `PurchaseOrder` table. If you wish to display the list of PO to your user, you usually don't need to retrieve that field, unless the user open the PO.

Many recent ORM, like nHibernate, offers lazy loading for columns, along with paging so you can retrieve a small amount of row.

Ayende [posted a rent](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/17/what-am-i-so-hung-up-on-unbounded-result-set.aspx) about loading unbounded result set two weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks Pierre-Alain.Yes i'm receving data over the course of the 5 min.The specificity of this table is that :it contains a column of type nvarchar(max)="article written by students" that is a long text.this problem is frustratin me because i use the same table in another stored proc called from .ajax and it lasts >5 min(it contains joins and brings the data with "article" column included

Comment: @Pierre-Alain ,i have executed the same query via RDP in the server ,it taks 1 second.the problem is that i'm calling a stored procedure using the same table .it takes 1 second via rdp but >5 min when i'm tesing.

Comment: will that be the same result when other users are connecting to my website.that's bad

Comment: if you query while being on the server, you eliminate the transport factor. This is not a real situation. And yes, if you are experiencing this on a production website, then all of your customer are also experiencing delay.

Comment: @Pierre:actually i'm using the table in a stored procedure.I have used to SQL Server Profiler to track what's heppening in the database.When i'm debugging,i see all procedure begin just after calling them,only this one i don't see the the begining of its execution when i call it from c#

Comment: my stored has 10 parameters :10 Tables(use defined table type)

Answer (score 0):

You're right - the select query shouldn't take that long. It's not the number of rows. Likely it's the type of data you've got on that table/view, and perhaps the storage configuration (slow disk, filegroups config, etc).

Some ideas to consider to remedy this performance problem:

- be specific in the columns that you want to retrieve. For ad-hoc queries, `SELECT *` is fine, but recognize that the RDBMS will work slightly harder to determine which columns are on the table/view.
- gathering the values any columns of datatype `text`, `varbinary` will take proportionally longer depending on the data within those fields.
- consider the indexes (do you have any?) on the table/view?
- is this a Prod database, where more/other activity might be hitting this table?

If you edit your question, perhaps include the full table definition so that we can get a real look at what's happening with the datatypes.

Comment: Anonymous random downvoter: care to explain how this answer doesn't help the OP solve the problem?

Comment: @p.campell:the specificity of my table is that it contains a column of type nvarchar(max)=long text typed by users.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you consider OMG Ponies's recommendation - it could be due to the bandwidth between the box and your machine, so

- try to remote the box and see how long the query takes on that machine.
- If it takes almost same amount of time, then the problem lies either in the database design or underlying hardware, or other factors (table datatypes, wrong indexes, overall load on the machine, overall hits to this table, etc)
- if it takes significantly less amount of time, then the problem is surely between your machine and the box - ideally this shouldn't be a big problem, because the web server will be closer to the db server, probably on same LAN (so it should be much faster in the real world). Also, I'm sure you wouldn't use a 'Select *' in the actual app to pick 29000 rows, so it shouldn't create a lot of problem.